# Crown Molding Nightmare

Tags: trim, trim-carpentry

So we’re doing an ikea hack to make these book shelves look like built-ins. That beam near the top will have a rolling library ladder attached to it. Above that will be small box-like shelves that span the entire width of the bookshelf, like you see in the upper right. The issue I’m facing is that at the very top, we want to put crown molding around the book shelf so that it meets the ceiling. The issue is that we have this bizarre corner next to the fireplace and I worry the top of the bookshelf crown molding is going to run into the existing crown molding. Any tips on what to do about this corner, or how to bring this bookshelf up to the ceiling without it looking terrible next to the existing crown molding?

[image]

Comment: I would match the bookshelves to that corner.  hide anything past it.  Then turn that outside corner into an inside corner for the crown moulding.

Comment: @crip659 copy, paste in answer box, and away you go.

Comment: @crip659 what do you mean by ‘hide anything past it’. Like close off the entire corner between the bookshelf and the fireplace wall? You might not be able to see it well in that photo but the gap is about 6” and is a really bizarre angle

Comment: I hate it when pictures lie.  I was guessing maybe two inches at most for the bottom.  maybe some more for the top.  Can you raise it so the top of the small boxes/ or one long box be close enough to the ceiling to use the moulding, or just leave everything as is as shown in the picture?  It won't have that built in look, but built ins go right to the top.

Comment: Yeah, fireplace molding aside I don't know how you will "... put crown molding around the book shelf so that it meets the ceiling" when those boxes appear to be like 8"-10" from the ceiling?

Comment: @StevePayne you really should provide a sketch showing plan and elevation dimensions.

Comment: How are you planning on crown molding on top of the bookcase reaching up to the ceiling?